# How to clear pg_xlog directory?

Tags: postgresql, transaction-log, postgresql-9.4

I have found myself in a situation where the pg_xlog contains 60GB of data due to a wrong configuration option set.

I had setup the `wal_level`, `archive_mode=on` and `archive_command` for barman which then got uninstalled. Can I simply comment these options as per default postgresql.conf config file and delete the files in the pg_xlog directory?

What is the correct procedure to remove these files in order to avoid database corruption?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41161495/330315

Comment: I think [pg_archivecleanup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgarchivecleanup.html) would have been another option if you check the "Latest checkpoint's REDO WAL file" from `pg_controldata`

Comment: I did read about that but couldn't find the `pg_controldata` command. It's not present in my installation (Debian)

Answer (score 8):

Managed to solve it quite simply. Stopped the db, commented the options in postgresql.conf and restarted. PostgreSQL took care of deleting everything automatically.

Comment: Correct. Congratulations, you didn't corrupt your database! `pg_archivecleanup` would also be OK *if* you didn't have WAL archiving (barman, etc) or streaming replicas.

Comment: What all are the options did you comment in postgresql.conf file ?

Comment: The ones stated in the question.

Comment: Actually, my PG started outputting 'archive command failed' **after** I used `pg_archivecleanup`. I had to nevertheless stop the DB, comment-out those params and restart.

Answer (score 0):

In cases when the database does not clean this directory automatically, you can use `pg_resetxlog`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgresetxlog.html

This command was renamed to `pg_resetwal` in the latest database version: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-pgresetxlog.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-pgresetwal.html

Be very careful with this command.

Create a full database backup before such a procedure because this command might break some DB transactions.

It should be run in the PostgreSQL directory. Probably, this command will also prompt you to add some missing files or delete a lock file before running.

Comment: So bold of you to suggest this; have you ever tried it? My guess would be, you haven't, since you're linking to the 9.2 version of the docs.

Comment: To anyone crazy enough to follow this advice, be sure to read the documentation page _in full_ before proceeding.

Comment: yes, I tried it in postgres 9. my xlog grew very big due to some database crashes. This was the only way to fix its size. Database was safely dumped and restored after that. I got no issues at all. I don't understand your panic - this method was also tested by my co-worker before and guess what, no issues.