# postgresql + how to recover the wals files

Tags: postgresql, linux, postgresql-9.2

we have postgresql version 9.x on rhel machine , postgresql is the DB of the ambari server

some of the files under folder - `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog` was deleted by mistake

from total 487 files only 5 files was deleted by mistake

example ( not the real files - only to show similar state )

```
cd /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog
[root@Ambari_server pg_xlog]# ls -ltr | more
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F1
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F2
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F3
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F4
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F5
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000F6
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000F7
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000F8
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000F9
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000FA
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000FB
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000FC
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000FD
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 0000000100000000000000FE
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000000
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000001
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000002
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000003
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000004
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000005
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 000000010000000100000006
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 000000010000000100000007
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 000000010000000100000008
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 000000010000000100000009
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 00000001000000010000000A
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 00000001000000010000000B
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2020 00000001000000010000000C
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2020 00000001000000010000000D
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2020 00000001000000010000000E
.
.
.
.
```

for now when we try to start the postgresql as s`ystemctl status postgresql.service` , we get the error - `could not open critical system index 2662`

unfortunately we not have postgresql backup

what are the options that we can do in order to recover the wals files ( `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog` ) that are missing?

**per suggestion we do the following:**

```
[root@master2 base]# su postgres

bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.2.13)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT current_database();
 current_database
------------------
 postgres
(1 row)



ls -ltr /var/lib/pgsql/data
total 56
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres     4 Mar 14 07:18 PG_VERSION
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Mar 14 07:18 pg_twophase
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Mar 14 07:18 pg_tblspc
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Mar 14 07:18 pg_snapshots
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Mar 14 07:18 pg_serial
drwx------. 4 postgres postgres    34 Mar 14 07:18 pg_multixact
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  1636 Mar 14 07:18 pg_ident.conf
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    17 Mar 14 07:18 pg_clog
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  4232 Mar 14 07:18 pg_hba_bak.conf.old
drwx------. 7 postgres postgres    62 Mar 14 07:21 base
-rw-r--r--. 1 postgres postgres  4454 Mar 14 08:10 pg_hba.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 postgres postgres 19813 Mar 14 08:10 postgresql.conf
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    81 Mar 16 00:00 pg_log
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    17 Mar 16 02:30 pg_subtrans
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    57 Mar 16 07:05 postmaster.opts
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 Mar 16 07:45 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    17 Mar 16 07:45 pg_notify
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 Mar 16 07:45 global
drwx------. 3 postgres postgres  4096 Mar 16 07:51 pg_xlog



[root@master2 base]#  systemctl stop postgresql.service
[root@master2 base]# su postgres
bash-4.2$
bash-4.2$
bash-4.2$  postgres --single -O -P -D /var/lib/pgsql/data/ postgres

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.2.13
backend> REINDEX SYSTEM
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input at character 16
STATEMENT:  REINDEX SYSTEM

backend>
```

Comment: Note that Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: ok I am understand but regarding to my case what we can do?

Comment: perhaps this?  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166143/how-to-clear-pg-xlog-directory

Comment: this link is to purge the files , but what about recover the files that deleted , is it possible?

Comment: not understand regarding the link the purge of the files should be the solution ?

Comment: I don't believe you can recover those files, as you have no backup. The link was to allow you to start the database.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you didn't only remove WAL segments, but you also dropped critical system objects. In case of point, 2662 is the “primary key” index on the system catalog table `pg_class`:

```
SELECT relname, relkind FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 2662;

      relname       | relkind 
--------------------+---------
 pg_class_oid_index | i
(1 row)

\d pg_class_oid_index

Index "pg_catalog.pg_class_oid_index"
 Column | Type | Key? | Definition 
--------+------+------+------------
 oid    | oid  | yes  | oid
unique, btree, for table "pg_catalog.pg_class"
```

You could try to stop the database, start it in single user mode and rebuild the index:

```bash
postgres --single -O -P -D /path/to/data/directory dbname

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 13.2
backend> REINDEX SYSTEM dbname
```

If that fixes the immediate problem, dump the database right away and restore it into a new cluster.

If not, you have probably lost your database. You can hire an expert to salvage all data possible.

Comment: first thank you so much for your answer and effort , I update my question according to your suggestion but still get some issue , , maybe I was wrong with something? you can see the update under "per suggestion we do the following:"

Comment: Did that fix the problem?

Comment: still not because , I not sure if I was do the things in the right way , did you saw the section - per suggestion we do the following:?

Comment: let me know if you need other results from my postgresql machine?

Comment: Oh, sorry - I forgot the database name.

Comment: but now we cant even start the postgresql service and we get postgres --single -O -P -D /var/lib/pgsql/data/ postgres
"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.

Comment: any other suggestion?

Comment: Of course you cannot do it as user `root`. You need to be `postgres`. But, to tell you the truth, it is extremely unlikely that a) the `REINDEX` will succeed and b) it will fix all your problems. You are best advised to either forget about these data or hire an expert.

Comment: so I run the  postgres --single -O -P -D /var/lib/pgsql/data/ postgres  , and from output I can see only this --> 

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.2.24

Comment: is this is good indication

Comment: Yes, but does the `REINDEX` succeed? Is the database dumpable after that?